# C# create temporary url to receive HTTP request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web-applications, web

Hi, I am new to C# and website design. I am working on a console application that will temporarily create a valid URL and receive the HTTP request for a short time. Can anyone help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I can't tell if you want to write a client that creates a string like `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, makes a request and captures the response, or a server that will accept a request, e.g. for `ftp://www.mytest.disorg` and do something.  For a short time.

Comment: You could create a simple WCF client, and dynamically host at a temporary endpoint, receive what you need to receive, and shut down/start over. A simple example (replace net.tcp with http)  http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you only need to make a [RewritePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d.aspx) to any call. This can be done on global.asax as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Any call, eg WhatEverName.aspx -> it will call the ExistingFile.aspx
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("ExistingFile.aspx");
}
```